# SQL Impala- Aggregation with analytic function causes group by AnalysisException

Tags: sql, group-by, impala, analytic-functions

I have a query where I want to calculate the percentage of sales of a certain product within its category. Thus I calculate the amount sales per product and use an analytic function and partition by category.

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(sales)/(SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY category))
FROM table1 
GROUP BY product_id
```

I get this error message:

```
AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): sum(sales) / ((sum(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY category)))
```

Anyone that know how to solve this and why it happens?

Comment: Is ````product_id```` an unique value?, because if so, ````group by product_id```` doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Could you try ````SELECT product_id, sales / SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY category)
FROM table1;````?

Comment: Correct, product_id is unique. The query works if I write: 
SELECT product_id, SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY category)
FROM table1; 

If I just write: SELECT product_id, sales / SUM(sales) OVER(PARTITION BY category) FROM table1; Won't it just take the first available sales value for each product_id? (each row in table1 is a product and a date). I think I need to sum the sales over a defined period of time per product_id and divide it by the sum of sales for that category in order to get the right percentage value.

Comment: I don't think so, but you could try with a few values, I mean with a small table with ten records for example and calculate by hand the expected result and see what the query produces. It was what I did. Please let me know if you try it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the aggregation function in the window function:

```
SELECT product_id, category,
       (SUM(sales) /
        SUM( SUM(sales) ) OVER (PARTITION BY category))
-------------^ aggregation function
--------^ window function
       )
FROM table1 
GROUP BY product_id, category;
```

Combining aggregation and analytic functions looks strange at first (at least it did to me).  Just remember that the aggregation functions are evaluated first, so the inner `SUM(sales)` is the result of the aggregation.  The other `SUM()` is the window function.

Comment: I get AnalysisException: 
select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): (sum(sales) / sum(sum(sales)) OVER (PARTITION BY category))

SELECT product_id,
       (  SUM(sales) /
          SUM( SUM(sales) ) OVER (PARTITION BY category))
       )
FROM table1 
GROUP BY product_id.

without group by i get: AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): product_id

group by 1,2 i get: 
AnalysisException: GROUP BY expression must not contain aggregate functions: 2

Comment: @Energizer1 . . . You just ned `category` in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have a good example that fits with your question:

Table example

```sql
+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| order_id | cust_id | empl_id | total  |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| 1        | c       | 1       | 24.78  |
| 2        | a       | 4       | 28.54  |
| 3        | b       | 3       | 48.69  |
| 4        | b       | 3       | -16.39 |
| 5        | z       | 2       | 29.92  |
| 6        | z       | 3       | 12.50  |
| 7        | a       | 4       | 10.20  |
| 8        | c       | 1       | 5.22   |
+----------+---------+---------+--------+
```

query

```sql
SELECT order_id, total / (SUM(total) OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id)) AS percentage
FROM orders
ORDER BY order_id;
```

result

```sql
+----------+------------+
| order_id | percentage |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | 0.82       |
| 2        | 0.73       |
| 3        | 1.50       |
| 4        | -0.50      |
| 5        | 0.70       |
| 6        | 0.29       |
| 7        | 0.26       |
| 8        | 0.17       |
+----------+------------+
```

as you can see, for example, for `cust_id --> c` there are two values `24,78` and `5,22` that `sum = 30.00` and `percentage` is `24,78 --> 0.82` and `5,22 --> 0.17`

Please review if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Impala does not seem to support analytic functions this way, I solved with sub-queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.product_id, (t2.sales/t2.tot_sales_cat) AS perc_cat_spend 
FROM( 
        SELECT t1.product_id, SUM(t1.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.category) AS tot_sales_cat, t4.prod_sales 
        FROM table1 as t1 
        JOIN(   SELECT  t1.product_id, SUM(t1.sales) AS prod_sales 
                FROM table1 AS t1 
                GROUP BY 1
            )   AS t4 ON t4.product_id=t1.product_id;
```